# Timer countdown runs only once not following while loop?

Tags: javascript, php

Each time while loop run it create another table row and show related data, i want to show countdown timer in column of each row(to show time elapsing). My below script run only once. Do you have another idea how to do it or do something with this?? i wrote below code within the php while loop but runs only once. Please help

```
<script> 
counter=0;
</script>
<?php
$count=0;
while($rowp = $resultp->fetch_assoc()) {
echo <td><p id='demo",$count,"'></p></td>
?>
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $enterytime1; ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = now - countDownDate;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo" + counter).innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: php veriable $enterytime1 change its value every time while loop runs.

Comment: i use counter variable equal to 0 before while loop starts but still nothing.. :(

Comment: Are you printing the whole script in the while loop?

Comment: yes i m doing, but define counter=0 before while loop

Comment: But if the counter is javascript variable how are you incrementing it with a php loop?

Comment: I don't know php, but I am not sure `echo` works without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to create new countdown for all column

Comment: it did but script runs only once :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably your if condition is `true` - countDownDate > now - and it terminates interval.

Comment: no everything works fine, only want script to runs every time when whileloop runs

Comment: where is while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it goes directly to EXPIRED right? You have the wrong order. It should be the other way around:

var distance = countDownDate - now;

Comment: no it does not. order is okay, problem is script runs only once

Comment: If I put a future date in this fiddle, using your code, it goes directly to expired: https://jsfiddle.net/pcqopt6v/. However if you exchange the values, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/bjkr8mm9/2/  If you are 100% sure this is not the issue, then the other thing it could be happening is that you are closing the window where the JS is running.

Comment: Well, I dont see how you iterate over the count variable. it seems is always 0. Also, do you actually get to see a timer in your code? How do you know if runs once?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `php` code to the date and i changed the `distance` calculation.  Try this if there is any change then let me know

```js
var countDownDate = new Date(2017, 2, 10, 12, 9, 40, 0).getTime();
counter = 0;
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  counter++;
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute("id", "demo" + counter);
  var node = document.createTextNode(days + "days " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
  newDiv.appendChild(node);
  if (document.getElementById("demo" + counter) != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo" + counter).innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  } else {
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
  if (counter > 10)
    counter = 0;

}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Comment: I am using counter because i am countdown on each row of loop. as i mentioned time for every row is change.

Comment: actually while loop fetch data from mysql query so it depends on query.

Comment: I have updated the code can you tell me is this you want ? If not then explain me your requirement exactly

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but this is not what i am looking for. please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688526/need-a-countdown-timer-in-each-row-while-loop-execute